# Lookup multiple columns based on their names in Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql, string-matching, lookup-tables, azure-sql-server

Issue: I have 100 tables that can have different column names for full name, date of birth, email and Id. For example: Table 1 has full name as Emp name,dob, work email and national id. Table 2 might have Full Nm, date of birth, Wrk Email, NID and Table 3 might have Full Name, birth date, Work Em, NatID and so on..for 10 or more different tables

Full Name + DOB is considered as unique column

What I need is a query or an automated way to pick those probable columns with different names and lookup those column values against a reference table which has those  columns and its values (full name, date of birth, work email, national id) and if I found a match then

Desired result: I need to retrieve the table name that found a match, column name that found a match, value that matched and return "no match" if match not found

I tried using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` but had no luck yet. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're fine with looking at `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`. Unless I've not followed you, you can surely do this?

```
select c.COLUMN_NAME, IsNull(m.Found,'No Match') Matches
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
outer apply (
    select column_name + ' is in ' + table_name Found
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS x
    where x.COLUMN_NAME =c.COLUMN_NAME and x.TABLE_NAME !=c.TABLE_NAME
)m
where c.table_name='MasterList'
```

Create your MasterList table with all the column variants you want to locate in other tables, then this will list you all the tables in the database with the columns that match.

Answer (score 0):

If its 10 tables then presumably you can check them out in advance and know which columns you want to look at. The challenge is then to combine all that into one query. You could do it with a bunch of UNIONS, like this:

```
select [Emp name] as Name, [dob] as DateOfBirth, [work email] as Email, [national id] as ID, 'Table1' as TableName
from Table1
UNION 
select [Full Nm] as Name, [date of birth] as DateOfBirth, [Wrk Email] as Email, [NID] as ID, 'Table2' as TableName
from Table2
UNION
select [Full Name] as Name, [birth date] as DateOfBirth, [Work Em] as Email, [NatID] as ID, 'Table3' as TableName
from Table3
UNION
--etc etc
```

Note how we are adding a TableName column to tell us which table each item comes from.

To query that dataset as a whole you would need to declare it as a view or something like that, or nest it within another SELECT like this:

```
select Name, DateOfBirth, Email, ID, TableName
from (
    select [Emp name] as Name, [dob] as DateOfBirth, [work email] as Email, [national id] as ID, 'Table1' as TableName
    from Table1
    UNION 
    select [Full Nm] as Name, [date of birth] as DateOfBirth, [Wrk Email] as Email, [NID] as ID, 'Table2' as TableName
    from Table2
    UNION
    select [Full Name] as Name, [birth date] as DateOfBirth, [Work Em] as Email, [NatID] as ID, 'Table3' as TableName
    from Table3
    UNION
    --etc etc
) giveitaname
WHERE [Name] = 'Joe Bloggs' and [DateOfBirth] = '01/Feb/1999'
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am expecting it to be 10 as of now for my poc but acutally it could be more than that, could be 60-100  excel files that I am converting into sql tables. Also how can we look this up to the reference table? . I dont want to look into each table and find out what the name of the columns are, need something more dynamic

Comment: Thats hard, because you'd have to have fuzzy logic around recognising the column names. Are the columns always in the same order, perhaps?

Comment: Not always in the same order. I tried something like this but not sure how I can convert this to my requirement.

Comment: DECLARE cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET cmd = STUFF((
SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT '+QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)+' FROM '+QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%email%' 
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,11,'')
;

EXEC( @cmd);

Comment: @cmd=cmd in the above query

Comment: Something like that, but you only need to grok the columns in each Excel file once, whereas you'll have to search them many times. So you have a table called 'ColumnHints' or something that records the column names of interest for each table. How you build that table, I'm not sure....

Comment: However carefully you tune it, someone will always come up with column names you're not expecting. Its going to have to be a semi manual process I think.

Comment: Semi manual process is fine. I need to know how I can lookup to the result of my above query using stuff to the reference table?

Comment: The main problem is you need a loop to build the query, and loops are awkward in SQL. Here's a solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/69c50/16